# Runtime requirements for react-intl with NextJs - how to polyfill?

Tags: next.js, react-intl

I'm trying out a new way to integrate react-intl with NextJS. I've had a lot of problems with the example from the official repo. Basic translations work. But whenever I navigate to a page with a german translation I see this error:

```
Error: [@formatjs/intl Error MISSING_DATA] Missing locale data for locale: "de" in Intl.DateTimeFormat. Using default locale: "en" as fallback. See https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl#runtime-requirements for more details 

    at new MissingDataError (/Users/**s/Code/hr-tool/hr-nextjs/node_modules/@formatjs/intl/src/error.js:45:23)
    at Object.createIntl (/Users/**/Code/hr-tool/hr-nextjs/node_modules/@formatjs/intl/src/create-intl.js:39:17)
    at Object.createIntl (/Users/**/Code/hr-tool/hr-nextjs/node_modules/react-intl/src/components/provider.js:59:27)
    at new IntlProvider (/Users/**/Code/hr-tool/hr-nextjs/node_modules/react-intl/src/components/provider.js:79:27)
    at processChild (/Users/**/Code/hr-tool/hr-nextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3305:14)
    at resolve (/Users/**/Code/hr-tool/hr-nextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3270:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/Users/**/Code/hr-tool/hr-nextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3753:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/Users/**/Code/hr-tool/hr-nextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at renderToString (/Users/**/Code/hr-tool/hr-nextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
    at Object.renderPage (/Users/**/Code/hr-tool/hr-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:52:851) {
  code: 'MISSING_DATA'
```

The solution is to add polyfill for the language data as [described here](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl). But I'm having problems installing the polyfill. The error message won't disappear. The next docs say to apply polyfills as a top-level import in the `app.js` [file](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features#custom-polyfills). This did not work. I also tried loading the polyfills asynchronously from getInitialProps (also did not work). I'm quite stuck. Maybe you can help.

Comment: Maybe you could try [react-intl-universal](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal) with next.js. Here is app example [integrating react-intl-universal with NextJS](https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal/tree/master/packages/react-intl-universal/examples/browser-example)